# If I set TOTALBILLINGCYCLES to zero in paypal recurring payment, will that payment profile live forever?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am bit confused about recurring payment and it's lifetime. I am trying to figure out do I have to update recurring payment profile somehow after that year passes or not. I am reading from https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/createrecurringpaymentsprofile-api-operation-nvp#id09BNA01I0E9 following:

```
The combination of BillingPeriod and BillingFrequency cannot exceed one year.
```

But there is also a TOTALBILLINGCYCLES param which states

```
For the regular payment period, if no value is specified or 
the value is 0, the regular payment period continues until the 
profile is canceled or deactivated.
```

It suggests that I don't need to do anything with profile if I'ts set to zero. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BillingPeriod` and `BillingFrequency` are different from the lifetime of the recurring billing account.

`BillingPeriod` is how long should Paypal wait between charges? Daily? Weekly? Monthly?

`BillingFrequency` is how many times in a year will this user be charged.

So if you have a `BillingPeriod` of weekly and a `BillingFrequency` of 52 the user will be charged every week of the year. If you have a `BillingPeriod` of weekly and a `BillingFrequency` of 26 the user will be charged every week for the first half of the year and then they will not be billed anymore.

`TOTALBILLINGCYCLES` is how long do you want this subscription to run for. If you set it to zero it runs forever (until cancelled). If you set it to 3 then it will bill the user for three billings cycles (3 years) and then terminate itself.

Comment: I think I can consider it as YES to my original question and I can confirm it.

Comment: If we set it to 3 will it bill first payment immediately on PROFILESTARTDATE? Btw, what happens if TOTALBILLINGCYCLES is set to 1?